# How to make weighted list with list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a list `w` where `w[i]` represents the number of times `i` should be present in the final result.

For example, if:

```
w = [1, 3, 4]
```

then the resulting list should be:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Notice there is one 0, three 1's, and four 2's.

I have tried to accomplish this with the list comprehension:

```
w_list = [[i]*w[i] for i in range(len(w))]
```

but of course this doesn't quite work, giving me this:

```
[[0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

How can I write a list comprehension to get me the desired result, like in the example?

Comment: See also: https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/

Answer (score 3):

You could use a double loop to flatten `w_list`:

```
w_list = [x for num, i in enumerate(w) for x in [num] * i]
```

or

```
w_list = [x for i in range(len(w)) for x in [i]*w[i]]
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative solution you might like.

```
w = [1, 3, 4]
print([i for i in range(len(w)) for _ in range(w[i])])
```

results in `[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]` as desired.

Alternatively, `[i for i,n in enumerate(w) for _ in range(n)]` accomplishes the same thing.